# Weird cube shape

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to create a cube with both indices and vertices. I'm able to draw them, but they look kinda weird.

[image]

Here's my code. It has something to do with either the vertices or indices, but I'm not sure which:

```
public void Draw(BasicEffect effect)
{
    foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();
        device.SetVertexBuffer(cubeVertexBuffer);
        device.Indices = iBuffer;
        device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0,  8, 0, 12);
    }
}

private void SetUpIndices()
{
    indices = new short[36];

    indices[0] = 0;
    indices[1] = 3;
    indices[2] = 2;

    indices[3] = 2;
    indices[4] = 1;
    indices[5] = 0;

    indices[6] = 4;
    indices[7] = 7;
    indices[8] = 6;

    indices[9] = 6;
    indices[10] = 5;
    indices[11] = 4;

    indices[12] = 1;
    indices[13] = 2;
    indices[14] = 6;

    indices[15] = 6;
    indices[16] = 5;
    indices[17] = 1;

    indices[18] = 4;
    indices[19] = 7;
    indices[20] = 3;

    indices[21] = 3;
    indices[22] = 0;
    indices[23] = 4;

    indices[24] = 4;
    indices[25] = 0;
    indices[26] = 1;

    indices[27] = 1;
    indices[28] = 5;
    indices[29] = 4;

    indices[30] = 3;
    indices[31] = 7;
    indices[32] = 6;

    indices[33] = 6;
    indices[34] = 2;
    indices[35] = 3;

    iBuffer = new IndexBuffer(device, typeof(short), 36, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
    iBuffer.SetData(indices);
}

private void SetUpVertices()
{
    vertices = new VertexPositionColor[8];


    vertices[0] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), color);
    vertices[1] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), color);
    vertices[2] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1, 1, 0), color);
    vertices[3] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), color);
    vertices[4] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 0, -1), color);
    vertices[5] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 1, -1), color);
    vertices[6] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1, 1, -1), color);
    vertices[7] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1, 0, -1), color);

    cubeVertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, typeof(VertexPositionColor), 8, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
    cubeVertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(vertices);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for editing the post. I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do a wild guess and say its because of messed order of vertices in your indices (I would call them triangles further).

Usually in 3d engines you have to set up order of vertices in triangles so they all are ordered same - i.e. clockwise or counter-clockwise - when you look at them from outside of shape they form.
Speaking mathematically all normals of triangles in your shape should be directed either inside or outside of shape. The direction of normal tells 3d engine when to draw triangles - engine can do two times less work if it draws triangles only on one side - the insides of a solid objects in 99,99% cases are not to be seen by user.

In your case look at indices 032 and 476 - they should be either 032/467 or 023/476. And so on.

Comment: Thanks. My plan is to eventually only draw the sides of each cube that are seen, but I need to actually get the cube shape working correctly first lol

Comment: Oh and the cubes will also have a single texture too. Which I'll need more values when that happens

Comment: Looking at picture you provided I think XNA draws only visible sides of cubes already. Its usually a default behaviour.

Comment: As I said - engine can understand what side is inside and what is outside ONLY by order of vertices in indices, and this data should be provided by you. In case you provide some of indices are just wrongly ordered. Have you managed to draw correct cubes btw?

Comment: I haven't. I've been messing around with the order of them but they still look deformed

Comment: Try following order : 023 012 156 162 267 273 476 465 145 104 074 037

Comment: Worked perfectly!! But by moving the camera inside of the cubes you can see that the sides adjacent to other sides are still being drawn. So XNA doesn't do it for you sadly

Comment: Means my memory is worse that I hoped. But there definitely should be an option for drawing solid outsides only.

Comment: You'd think there would be. I know that backface culling is automatic, unless you change the state of it. But in this case I'd need to check each vertex or index to see if it's adjacent to another in order to draw it or not